# Filled colour and white border geom_points in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-point

How to change the points such that it is filled with color on the inside (according to the factor) but has a white border on the outside? I can't find an example with the standard `pch` chart

```
library(data.table)
A = data.table(x = 1:4, y = 1:4, z = c('A','A','B','B'))

ggplot(A) + geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y, color = z)) + facet_grid(~z) + theme_bw()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shape you are looking for is `shape=21`. Afterwards map your factor on the `fill` aes and set the color for the outline as an argument:

Note: I have set the color to black for the reprex as white isn't really visible.

```r
library(ggplot2)
A <- data.frame(x = 1:4, y = 1:4, z = c("A", "A", "B", "B"))

ggplot(A) +
  geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y, fill = z), shape = 21, color = "black", size = 5, stroke = 1) +
  facet_grid(~z) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]